# Chinese Character is not displaying correctly

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I am using openrowset to import data from sql server to another sql server. One of the column data is a chinese character. When i successfully import to my sql server, the column data which is chinese character show weird sign on my table. The data type for the column from the external is varchar where the data type for the column from my side is nvarchar.

Is there any way i can do so that the data can be display properly?

P.S. The weird character show is °»´ú³q¹DÂ_½u

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that's wha'ts caused the problem in the first place - using ANSI strings with codepages. While the OP could work around this using a COLLATE statement (not OPENROWSET), the real fix is to convert the varchar column to nvarchar. Chinese is *the* canonical example for why Unicode and nvarchar should be used instead of varchar and code pages

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what good would that do? The remote server is *already* using a specific codepage. Probably the wrong one, because the SQL Server client libraries can automatically convert from varchar to nvarchar. You don't need OPENROWSET to specify a codepage, you can do that with COLLATE in the SELECT statement. Guessing how to reverse a wrong codepage though, is a lot trickier

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti besides, CODEPAGE is an option used for files, not executing queries against other databases

Comment: @missypooh First, how do you know there's a display problem? The font used by SSMS may not be able to display Chinese, even though the data is OK. What happens if you copy the data eg into Word? Second, what is the sign displayed for chinese characters? If the character is a question mark or � the data may already be lost - this is Unicode's [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) for data that can't be translated. What is the collation of the *remote* column that contains Chinese data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, i am using openrowset is because i need to access external sql server, unless you have an ideas how can i access external sql server to access the data. The character display is not question mark nor  � . is same very weird characer

Comment: What character? This *is* important - sometimes a wrong page results in weird but recoverable characters, sometimes there's no way to translate and the data is lost.  Also, what is the collation of the remote column? *Have you tried copy/pasting the text to make sure it isn't just your font that can't display Chinese?' As for querying another server, the easiest is to [create a linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) and reference the remote tables using a four part name, eg. `somesever.somedatabase.dbo.sometable`. This won't fix collation problems though

Comment: the collation of the remote column is varchar. I did try to copy and paste the text to word, and it is the same as show on the display. I have edit my question to show the weird character.

Comment: VARCHAR is the type, not the collation. Collations are roughly equivalent to code pages, eg. Latin1_General_CI_AS or Chinese_PRC_CI_AI.

Comment: the collation of the remote column is Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_CI_AS